# bash ssh script not outputting results to file

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, ssh, ping

Doing a simple script in work and I can't figure out why it will not output the results in another file.

`/tmp/system` stores the node list

```
#!/bin/bash
$results=restest.txt
for i in  $(cat /tmp/system); do
ping -c 1 $i
if [ $i = 0 ]; then
ssh $i ps -ef | grep ops | echo > $results
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

echo is not printing from stdin but rather its arguments (or a newline if there no arguments). So

```
echo file.txt
```

only prints 'file.txt', not the content of the file. Therefore your code only writes a newline to the file. You can use cat for printing stdin to stdout, but here it is useless, since you can pipe the grep output directly to the file:

```
ssh $i ps -ef | grep ops > $results
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that as well just to cover every angle and still does not work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the "echo" is not usefull here but this is not totally correct, if you want to execute come commands on a remote machine and get the output you should quote your commands

Answer (score 0):

first thank you for editing your code (it's more clear like this :) 
I have 2 or 3 advices :

1- when you want to store a value in variable dont use "$" symbole, this symbole is used to get the variable's value

ex:

> ```
>  MYVAR=3
>  echo MYVAR        "this will print MYVAR"
>  echo $MYVAR       "this will print 3"
> ```

2- always quote your values, specially if the value is comming from another command

3- To fix your script you need to quote the command executed on the remote machine,
then redirect the output to your file

ex:

> ```
> ssh user@MachineA "ls > file.txt"    "file.txt is created on machineA"
> ssh user@machineA "ls" > file.txt    "file.txt is created on YOUR machine"
> ```

so simply you can replace your last line by

> ```
> ssh $i "ps -ef | grep ops" > $results
> ```

try to use -ne in your test [bash classictest](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors. First, don't iterate over files like this. Second, `i` is the name of the host, not the exit status of `ping`. Third, the `echo` is unnecessary (and does not read from standard input). Lastly, `$` is only used for expanding a parameter, not assigning to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
results=restest.txt
while read -r host; do
    if ping -c 1 "$host"; then
        ssh "$host" ps -ef | grep ops > "$results"
    fi
done < /tmp/system
```